# FPDF Rotate Multi-Line Text Box

Tags: php, fpdf, fpdi

I would like to create a multi-line text box which is upside down.  The text box should be a fixed size, any texts that does not fit should be cut off.  The text box size should not be adjusted to fit the excess text, nor should the text be shrunk to fit the text box.

I can create a regular multi-line text box using the PDF_TextBox script here http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script52.php.

I can also rotate a single line of text using the RPDF script here http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script31.php.

How can I combine these two scripts to produce a multi-line rotated (upside down) text box?

Comment: What did you try? What stopped you from completing the code you want to write?

Comment: If you cannot figure out how to use FPDF (which is a garbage tool), but can do it in HTML, then using a HTML to PDF library will make development much easier. I've used domPdf for years. Just a suggestion.
If you choose to, read this: https://peterdev.pl/picking-a-php-tool-to-generate-pdfs/

Comment: I have to agree with Paul, FPDF is more efficient, but a lot harder to use. Especially if you are familiar with HTML/CSS and not so much with PHP.

Comment: For the text box with a maximum number of lines, you can use [this](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script16.php). To rotate it, you can use [that](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script2.php).

Comment: Multi-line text box works using
drawTextBox('Hello World!', 50, 20, 'L', 'T', true)

Rotating a single line text box works using
TextWithDirection($x, $y, 'Hello Upside Down World!', $direction='L')

I've tried editing the drawTextBox script to replace the Cell function with TextWithDirection, however Cell takes width and height as input whereas TextWithDirection takes x and y.  Output has all the upside down text boxes on top of each other, rather than one underneath the other as rows.

I've got an existing PDF that I want to add the text on top of, so don't think HTML would work?